# How to replace autogenerated product name in install dialog?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

I'm using WiX 3.9.1208.0 to generate installer and bootstrapper for my application. I've just added digital signature to avoid a yellow warning when the installer is executed. I now get a friendly dialog prompting for elevated privileges where a program name and verified publisher is displayed, but the program name is a random auto-generated value instead of the real product name used in the `<Product>` element in the .wxs file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)\Variables.wxi?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Product Id="*" Name="My Product" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.FileVersion.MyProductExe)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
```

[image: Dialog for elevated previleges]

Why isn't "My Product" displayed as Program name, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you paste the bootstrapper code as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **/d** argument to the [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to give a friendly name. I.e.: **/d "My Installer"**